# What is wrong with my fibonacci sequence program that uses "for loop"

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, fibonacci

```
def fibonacci(n):
    terms = [0,1]
    i = 2

    for i in terms[2:n+1]:
        terms.append(terms[i-1] + terms[i-2])
        return terms[n]

user_input= input ('Write the number order by which you want to know its corresponding value in the fibonacci sequence')
fibonacci_user_input = fibonacci(user_input)
print fibonacci_user_input
```

The semantic error cited in the Pyscripter Python 2.7.9 that I'm using regarding this program is that it returns the value `None`.
I'm just starting to learn Python and I have been finding what is wrong with this program for quite some time now.
I already discovered how to write Fibonacci sequence program using while loop and recursion and I'm just having a hard time using this process.

Comment: you `return` inside the for loop… that means you will return on the very first iteration, no matter how large N is…

Comment: Explain what seems to be wrong with this implementation relative to your other implementations.

Comment: Hint: When the function starts, what is the value of `terms[2:n+1]`? Why are you using the current contents of `terms` as the values of `i`?

Comment: just would like to ask more information on what changes might be possible to correct the program.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for i in terms[2:n+1]:
```

should be:

```
for i in range(2, n+1):
```

You're adding to `terms`, you don't want to iterate over its current contents.

Comment: Thanks. My program is running correctly now. There are two things that are wrong to the program and from what you said that the return line should not be inside the for loop and that I am iterating in the content of the terms list from what should be happening at the range of 2 to n-1.

Comment: You're definitely right about the `return` line. I wasn't sure about why you were adding 1 to `n`, but I think you're right that it should be `n-1`. You're adjusting for Python being 0-based in array index, but humans being 1-based when counting.

Comment: def fibonacci(n):
    terms = [0,1]
    i = 2

    for i in range(2:n+1):
        terms.append(terms[i-1] + terms[i-2])
    return terms[n-1]

user_input= input ('Write the number order by which you want to know its corresponding value in the fibonacci sequence')
fibonacci_user_input = fibonacci(user_input)
print fibonacci_user_input - the modified program ~ return terms[n-1] should be used instead of return terms[n].

Comment: Ah okay. I understand now. The program is perfectly fine when the for line is:  for i in range(2:n). My understanding about slicing list in Python(I evaluated range(2:n+1) to be "from 2 up to but not including n+1") is different from what it really is.

Answer (score 0):

This line

```
        terms.append(terms[i-1] + terms[i-2])
```

runs only once in the for loop no matter how large the value of n is.